# [Ubuntu 22.04][Wayland] Ubuntu taskbar does not remain in set position on reboot

Tags: wayland, dock

Ubuntu Dock does not remain in Settings set position on reboot

Scenario: I am running Displaylink across three monitors (one including the laptop display).

Under "Settings>Appearance>Dock>Show On" set to monitor 2.

Upon reboot the Dock jumps back to monitor 1.

This is possibly a bug given 22.04 is still in development and not official release.
I tried CLI entering ubuntu-bug but it does not allow entering of actual problem description to file a bug.
Is there a mehthod to make this stick from CLI?

Thanks

Comment: Ubutnu 22.04 is not released yet and therefore is **not** supported here. You should open a bug

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc.  *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*

Comment: I also have this problem, and Ubuntu 22.04 is very much released now. Is there a solution?